# Please , can you help me get rid of this error?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a code for a random password generator with python and flask. I have created both the front end and the backend yet every time i am trying to run it i get a json error:

> raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
> requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

this is my front end code:

```
import requests
import json
session=requests.session()
data={"letters":0,"symbols":0,"numbers":0}
header={"content-type": "application/json"}

print("Welcome to the PyPassword generator!")
while True:
        data ["letters"]=input("how many lettres would you like in your password? > ")
        data ["symbols"]=input("how many symbols would you like? > ")
        data ["numbers"]=input("how many numbers would you like? > ")
        print(data)
        r=session.post("http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/PyPassword_generator", data=json.dumps(data), headers=header)
        if r:
                break
        json_data=r.json()
        print(json_data)
```

EDIT: Ading the response from the server component

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 972, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\simplejson\__init__.py", line 525, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Downloads\client.py", line 19, in <module>
    json_data = r.json()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 976, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
b'<!doctype html>\n<html lang=en>\n<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>\n<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>\n<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>\n'

Process finished with exit code 1ode here
```

so this is the server code

```
from flask import Flask, request, session, jsonify,json
import random

class game:
    def __init__(self,lettres,symbols,numbers):
        self.letters=lettres
        self.symbols=symbols
        self.numbers=numbers
        self.app = Flask("Shmuel Api server",static_url_path='')
        self.app.secret_key="Secret"

        @self.app.route('/api/ PyPassword_generator', methods=['Get',"Post"])
        def PyPassword_generator():
            print(request.data)
            print(json.loads(request.data.decode("ascii")))
            a=int(request.json["letters"])
            b=int(request.json["symbols"])
            c=int(request.json["numbers"])
            password = self.test(a,b,c)
            jsonify({f"your password is : {password}"})

    def run(self):
        debug=True
        self.app.run(host='10.0.0.10', port='5000', debug=debug)



        password_list=[]
        for char in range(a):
            password_list.append(random.choice(self.letters))
        for char in range(b):
            password_list.append(random.choice(self.symbols))
        for char in range(c):
            password_list.append(random.choice(self.numbers))
        random.shuffle(password_list)

        password="".join(password_list)
        return password

mp=game(["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"],["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"],["!","#","$","%","&","(",")","*","+"])
mp.run()
```

and this is the response I get

```
* Serving Flask app 'Shmuel Api server' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://10.0.0.10:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 446-336-887
10.0.0.10 - - [11/Jun/2022 21:23:52] "POST /api/PyPassword_generator HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without seeing the code from the server component (running at `localhost:1337`), and understanding the response which comes back (insert the line `print(r.content)` after the `session.post` call, but before the `r.json` call, and show us the output of this, when the request is made, ideally with the full trackback).

Comment: Hey thx for the resonse, ill add what i got after the new input to the original post

Comment: You never posted the code for the server component, but method not allowed suggests you need to ensure this is in the list passed as the `methods` argument to the `app.route` decorator, something like: `@app.route('/api/PyPassword_generator', methods=['GET', 'POST'])` (assuming this is a plain Flask app).

Comment: My apologies, I will post it right away. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There's a space in the URL of the server component, and the methods must be in caps...

```
    @self.app.route('/api/ PyPassword_generator', methods=['Get',"Post"])
```

should look like:

```
    @self.app.route('/api/PyPassword_generator', methods=['GET',"POST"])
```

Defining Flask routes inside an object like this looks wrong though.  I would probably simplify it:

```
from flask import Flask, request, session, jsonify,json
import random

app = Flask("__name__")
app.config['SECRET_KEY']='make me super secret'

@app.route('/api/PyPassword_generator', methods=['GET',"POST"])
def PyPassword_generator():
    # print(request.data)
    # print(json.loads(request.data.decode("ascii")))
    try:
        submitted_data = request.get_json()
        
        a=int(submitted_data["letters"])
        b=int(submitted_data["symbols"])
        c=int(submitted_data["numbers"])
    
    except ValueError: # Some issue with the input
        return {'error': 'invalid input data'}, 400

    password = generate_password(a,b,c)
    return jsonify({'message': f"your password is : {password}"})
```

Then on the client end, simplify things, by using `requests` native json argument, which means you don't need to use the `json.dumps` or pass the headers either, as this arg automatically sets the Content-Type...

```
import requests
session=requests.session()
data={"letters":0,"symbols":0,"numbers":0}

print("Welcome to the PyPassword generator!")
while True:
    data["letters"]=input("how many lettres would you like in your password? > ")
    data["symbols"]=input("how many symbols would you like? > ")
    data["numbers"]=input("how many numbers would you like? > ")
    print(data)
    
    r = session.post("http://127.0.0.1:5005/api/PyPassword_generator", json=data)
    
    json_data=r.json()
    print(json_data)

    if r.ok:
        break
```

Of course generating passwords comes with its own security considerations, and I assume this is just for learning python.  **Transmitting passwords over the wire comes with security considerations you should understand first.**

With that in mind, instead of `random.shuffle` for this, perhaps investigate the python [`secrets` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html).  Let's implement the `generate_password` function, and instead only work with the input `a` to set the *length* of the overall password.  Using their example, you could have something like:

```
import secrets 
import string
def generate_password(a,b,c):

    alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
    password = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(a))
    return password
```

Now this all works like:

```
Welcome to the PyPassword generator!
how many lettres would you like in your password? > 20
how many symbols would you like? > 1
how many numbers would you like? > 1
{'letters': '20', 'symbols': '1', 'numbers': '1'}
{'message': 'your password is : R@!o]KFnqk`,+Wg{JQ:#'}
```

Of course some obvious changes required on your part, but hope this helps.

Comment: Thx so much! The problem is that my assignment was to use Class which you replaced. Is there any way you could help me using class? Thank you so much!